# Minecraft loading problems?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Minecraft loads extremely slow for me and (as far as I know) only me. Since it's not actually crashing I could not get a crash report, but instead I have recovered a launcher log. [Here's the pastebin.](http://pastebin.com/JiQ4mESF)

From what I can tell, it's trying and failing to download something. Also, I think Minecraft is still working from an old Java version, though I'm up to date on Java.

Is there a way to get it going at normal speed?

Comment: Downvotes? What'd I do?

Comment: I think it's because it's Minecraft. I think, though, that this question has nice information and seems quite solvable, unlike most Minecraft questions.

Answer (score 4):

From the log, I could tell that there was a missing file. So, an easy fix would be to delete your .minecraft folder and reinstall Minecraft.

First, though, you should attempt to fix Java. Start by uninstalling all versions of Java via Control Panel, then Programs and Features. After running all Java uninstallers, you can further ensure Java ain't Broke via [JavaRa.](https://singularlabs.com/software/javara/javara-download/) You can remove all excess Java files stored in the deep depths of your computer with this tool.

After all that, install the latest version of Java via [Java's main website.](https://java.com/en/) Java should be fixed.